# Agromonitoring POST Request for Polygon Creation

Tags: request, postman, polygon, geojson

So I am trying to follow the [documentation](https://agromonitoring.com/api/polygons) with the example for **Create a polygon**.
This request should return an ID that I should be able to GET as a geoTIFF/PNG or else afterwards.
I am using Postman to try my POST request - see the picture.
The response I get is:

```
"name": "UnprocessableEntityError",
"message": "Your polygon needs a name"
```

I followed the example and cannot seem to find the error - my body does define a name. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the Content-Type from text to JSON. Like this:

[image: Image of postman toolbar that shows various content type options]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I was expecting postman to send JSON already. If I do not select JSON from the dropdown, the headers shows a header key/value pair of 'Content-Type' and 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.